# WebDriver in C# (work with windows and synchronization)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I work with webDriver in #IE9 and I find one problem. If I started tests in Run mode, then all test fail because webDriver not exists (two window ie), but if I put breakpoint in tests and start tests Debug mode I have passed all tests. Please tell me, what do, because I don't know.
This my code:

```
private void MyMethods(IWebdriver driver)
{

    foreach (var item in driver.WindowHandles) // if I put breakpoint, I see 2 count Window Handles else this methods don't work.
    {
        if (driver.SwitchTo().Window(item).Title == "PortalSubMenuPopupForm")
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting code that takes more than one line, you need to prefix each line with 4 spaces.  The backtick doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has an "issue" with IE where new windows might not appear on the `WindowHandles` list right away.

The solution is either

- wait a **fixed amount** of time before calling d`river.WindowHandles`

or

- use the **`WebDriverWait` class** to wait for the number of elements under `WindowHandles` to change

I think the second one is more robust. Here is a quick implementation:

```
public void LaunchNewWindow(IWebElement element)
{
    int windowsBefore = driver.WindowHandles.Count;
    element.Click();

    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

    wait.Until((_driver) =>
    {
        return _driver.WindowHandles.Count != windowsBefore;
        //optionally use _driver.WindowHandles.Count > windowsBefore
    });
}
```

Now you can use the function like so:

```
IWebElement clickMe = //some element that launches a new window

LaunchNewWindow(clickMe);
foreach (var item in driver.WindowHandles)
{
   //etc.
}
```